# Add specific words to PyEnchant dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, spell-checking, pyenchant

I do not want to add a new dictionary to PyEnchant , instead I want to add single words to the dictionary with suggestions how to correct them. For example I have the code

```
import enchant
enchantdict = enchant.Dict("de_GE")
suggested_words = [enchantdict.suggest(word) for word in ['Kunden','Nr','201']]
```

where "Nr" is a short way of saying "Nummer" (meaning "Number" in English). I would like to add to the PyEnchant dictionary such, that it is able to suggest "Nummer" when it sees "Nr". How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're looking for `enchantdict.store_replacement('Nr', 'Nummer')`. It's explained in the [documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/api/enchant.html), not that hard to find.

Comment: Fair enough. Now that you are saying it, it's obvious - I did not recognize it before.